# How to write xpath to select item that doesnot have aria-hidden="true"?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to click `"Cancel"` button. So I tried writing an x-path that looks something like this :

```
//button[text()='Cancel']
```

But two elements are identified since two elements match the conditions as below, though one of the element is hidden :

```
<button type="button" class="gwt-Button button_action_id_9135994370013188418_9135995360013188733_compositepopup_3 TableCtrl-button cancel-button">Cancel</button>

<button type="button" class="gwt-Button button_action_id_9149469526113774095_9149539697213772969 TableCtrl-button cancel-button" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">Cancel</button>
```

Is there a way I could identify the element that does not have a tag like `'aria-hidden'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below XPath to match required (not hidden button):

```
//button[text()='Cancel' and not(@aria-hidden='true')]
```